# I have two windows services and am using nlogger and getting this exception in both services in web app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

Here are both event viewer logs. nlogger showing null exception and authorization issues.
I have added nlog.dll , config, xsd files in both services.

First:

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
   at Logging.NLogger..ctor()
   at PreIRGIService.PreIRGIService..ctor()
   at PreIRGIService.Program.Main()
```

Second:

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, Int32, Boolean, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, Int32)
   at NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.BaseFileAppender.UpdateCreationTime()
   at NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.BaseFileAppender.TryCreateFileStream(Boolean, Int32)
   at NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.BaseFileAppender.CreateFileStream(Boolean, Int32)
   at NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.RetryingMultiProcessFileAppender.Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
   at NLog.Targets.FileTarget.WriteToFile(System.String, System.ArraySegment1<Byte>, Boolean)
   at NLog.Targets.FileTarget.ProcessLogEvent(NLog.LogEventInfo, System.String, System.ArraySegment`1<Byte>)
   at NLog.Targets.FileTarget.Write(NLog.LogEventInfo)
   at NLog.Targets.Target.Write(NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo)
   at NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncThreadSafe(NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo)
   at NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncLogEvent(NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo)
   at NLog.LoggerImpl.WriteToTargetWithFilterChain(NLog.Targets.Target, NLog.Filters.FilterResult, NLog.LogEventInfo, NLog.Common.AsyncContinuation)
   at NLog.LoggerImpl.Write(System.Type, NLog.Internal.TargetWithFilterChain, NLog.LogEventInfo, NLog.LogFactory)
   at NLog.Logger.Info(System.String)
   at PreIRGIService.LogHelper.LogUsingNLog(PreIRGIService.TraceLevel, System.String)
   at PreIRGIService.LogHelper.LogDetails(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String[])
   at PreIRGIService.PreIRGIService.CheckConfigurationSettings()
   at PreIRGIService.PreIRGIService..ctor()
   at PreIRGIService.Program.Main()
```

Comment: For the second one, my best guess is the user under the service's process has no write privileges in the log file. Check the user of the service (services.msc > select your service in the list > properties > Log On tab

Comment: Yes @Luty you are right.. I tried the same and error resolved by selecting log on tab and selected Local System Account.

Comment: For the first issue, there was key missing in config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First Issue resolved by adding the missing key and value in config file.
- Second Issue resolved by selecting log on tab on my windows service and selected Local System Account. Screenshot attached below

[Windows Service Log On Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfiz6.png)